# Dynamic input array lost after PHP form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an HTML form, where after AJAX function appears a list of radio buttons inside Div element

```
<div id='carCompanies' style=" max-height:500px; overflow-y:auto"></div>
```

like this in PHP and HTML:

```
for ($i=0;$i<$locations;$i++){
     $locationDetailCode[$i] = $vehMatchedLocs->VehMatchedLoc[$i]->LocationDetail['Code'];
     echo '<input type="radio" name="carCompany[]" value = "'.$locationDetailCode[$i].'"><br>';
}
```

I wrote a jQuery function to check that dynamic content appeared:

```
 function getLocDetail(){
        var a=$('#carCompanies').find("input:checked");
        alert(a.val());
    }
```

And this function works and shows correct value. 
But after I submit the form this value is lost. This PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['carCompany'])){
        $companyLocDetail = $_POST["carCompany"];
        echo 'Company Location Detail: '.$companyLocDetail.'<br>';
}
```

does not do anything. Why is this not posting to PHP? I gladly appreciate someone would help me, thank you.

Comment: Are the dynamic fields appended inside the form tags ??

Comment: Yes, the 'carCompanies' Div is inside the form tags and the AJAX function appends the content to the 'carCompanies' Div

Comment: try  to edit `name="carCompany[]"` with `name="carCompany"`, and print all data from the form using `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: Ok, I tried it, it shows all the inputs except the ones that I need (radio buttons)

Comment: What about using a unique name per element? You could use name="carCompany[" + $i + "]"

Comment: Yes, tried it too now. I have also changed the JavaScript function to check the name of the checked element. Everything works, but lost after Submit

Answer (score 0):

the variable "carCompany" is an array of value.

```
if(isset($_POST['carCompany'])){
        foreach($_POST['carCompany'] AS $car_company){
            $companyLocDetail = $car_company;
            echo 'Company Location Detail: '.$companyLocDetail.'<br>';
        }
}
```

also you can var_dump your post to see what it contain.

Comment: checked that too, it also gives the list of all inputs, except the dynamic ones

Comment: Look like your DOM doesn't send your input. And i see you're sure the input is in in the form...
 "$.ajax" might help you to post your form onclick if you don't find why your field wasn't include in the HTML posted code

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange, but it works now. What I have done is that I have removed the HTML 'table' tag from the 'form' tag was inside this 'table' tag. Without 'table' tag it works. I don't know why this is happening. Maybe it will help somebody in future. Thank you all